# How to render a tree structure in hibernate with multiple tables?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need to retrieve a tree from a DB in which I have two tables defined:

- **node** Here I define a node element
- **relation** Here I define the tree structure by specifying parents and children making use of IDs

Looking on the Internet I only find examples with a single table, the node one, in which both nodes and relations are defined:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "tree")
public class Node { 

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id; 

    @NotNull 
    private String name; 

    @OneToMany 
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") 
    @OrderColumn 
    private List<Node> children = new LinkedList<Node>();

}
```

Even though it is simpler I don't like it very much because the underlying tables are not normalized.

Anyone can provide me with a simple example using two tables?

Comment: Please, add tables structure to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have two columns in Relationship table,

> |id | parent_id|
>
> Parent Node entry will update the parent_id against the id of the node

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="Relationship", joinColumns =  @JoinTable(name = "Relationship", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"))@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
 private Node parentNode;
```

> Similarly child node will update the id against the parent_id of the
>   node

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Relationship", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
 private Set<Node> childNodes;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you may create relation table containing two IDs - a node ID, and another node ID - the parent of this node in Nodes table.