# Hibernate composite pattern with many-to-many composition

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, composite

I want to create a tree structure where each node can have multiple parents and children. (So actually it is not really a tree but more of a network).

For example, we have an interface to implement the composition, a `User` class which is the leaf node and a `Group` class which builds the structure. There would be some check against recursion (adding a group to a group that had the first group as a parent somewhere).

```
interface GroupMember {
    boolean isLeaf();
}

class User implements GroupMember {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    boolean isLeaf() { return true; }
}

class Group implements GroupMember {
    private int id;
    private Set<GroupMember> members;
    boolean isLeaf() { return false; }

    public addMember(GroupMember newMember) {
        // Some check against recursion         
        members.add(newMember);
    }
}
```

I see the most efficient way of implementing this in the database would be to have a link table (though this is just a suggestion and not required):

```
TABLE GROUP_MEMBER
-------------------
PARENT_ID    NUMBER
CHILD_TYPE   CHAR(1)
CHILD_ID     NUMBER
```

However, I am not sure if Hibernate supports this design. It seems to me that in loading the `members` set in `Group` Hibernate would have to consider the discriminator in the `GROUP_MEMBER` table to decide which class to instantiate.

I have considered having group containing two sets to separately fetch the groups and users, but this seems less than ideal.

Comment: This one looks pretty similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333705/how-to-render-a-tree-structure-in-hibernate-with-multiple-tables

Comment: @racraman it only has one type though - hence no discriminator is required.

Comment: Do you mean that in the table `GROUP_MEMBER`  , `PARENT_ID`/ `CHILD_ID` does not have any physically FK constraint to a particular table ? Rather , it is just logically that can be reference to any kind of table provided that the refereeing table/entity implementing `GroupMember`?

Comment: @Ken Chan yes, in that case (unless Group and User use the same table). But it isn't required that an answer uses the GROUP_MEMBER table as suggested. It was just an example.

Comment: User never rewards bounty.

Comment: @rghome I don't know if I am getting the question right but why can't you have a single table. You can have a type column in it (for user an group), have a parent_id column which maps to id of the same table and implement a ManyToOne for parent and OneToMany for the set of children in the same entity. Won't that work ??

Comment: @Malkeith Singh Maybe - I don't know. But I would need at least two tables in total as the user information could be considerable.

Comment: As per my understanding, at the JPA level, wouldn't it be fine to have a single class (instead of User and Group, just one Node class), which has parent and child references enough to handle the scenario?.

Comment: A Node class (or I think it would be GroupMember here) could be used to handle the structure. There could be an additional table for User properties (fields in User not in Group).

Comment: @[rghome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3800782/rghome): How about 2 tables: Group and user for example with the User table having an id_parent as a *foreign-key* referencing the Group table's *id* and the Group table having of course an *id* and an *id_parent* that may be null?

Comment: For future reference: I came across this question: it seems similar and it has an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603742/help-regarding-composite-pattern-with-hibernate?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I'm wrong, but I don't agree with having CHILD_TYPE to be part part of GROUP_MEMBER. I's a CHILD implementation detail and should stay with it. By moving it to the CHILD table, you can use standard ManyToMany JPA mapping, which should make the life simpler.

- If desired, CHILD_TYPE can be a discriminator inside the CHILD table.
- I always recommend to have a FK. Bugs happen, and orphans in the database are always a huge headache.

Entities:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CHILD_TYPE", length = 1)
@Table(name = "MEMBERS", schema = "mtm")
@Data //lombok
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true) //lombok
public abstract class GroupMember {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "GROUP_MEMBER", schema = "mtm",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private Set<Group> parents = new HashSet<>();

    public abstract boolean isLeaf();
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("G")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
class Group extends GroupMember {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents")
    private Set<GroupMember> members = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return false;
    }

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("U")
@SecondaryTable(name = "USERS", schema = "mtm")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
class User extends GroupMember {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(table = "USERS")
    private String name;

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Schema:

```
create schema if not exists MTM;

CREATE TABLE MTM.MEMBERS (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    CHILD_TYPE   CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE MTM.GROUP_MEMBER (
    member_id INT,
    parent_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE MTM.users (
    id INT,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

Notes:

- Standard Hibernate MTM and inheritance strategies are implemented
- Common data is stored in the MEMBERS table and User specific inside USERS table (implemented using `@SecondaryTable`)
- Group data is stored entirely inside MEMBERS for efficiency (eliminates JOIN), but can be extended in the same way as User
- If required, an additional interface can be introduced for the `isLeaf()` property.

Comment: If User and Group are in different tables then you need a TYPE column to indicate which one your child_id is referring to. I am looking for a working solution. This feels more like a comment.

Comment: I think having User and Group in totally different tables is too error prone and would be a mistake. If you agree with the approach in general, but have a problem with entity declarations, I can draft them for you

Comment: I think you don't understand. The User class is the leaf node. It could potentially have a lot more properties. The Group class is used to create the structure. The only thing they have in common is that they can both be children of Group.

Comment: There could be a common table for both, but User would at least require an additional table for its properties.

Comment: Thanks for the edits - it seems like a good answer now and I'm sorry it came a bit late for the bounty. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Actually it came on time. There is always a grace of 24 hours. But if you like the answer, you can still mark it as answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `@NamedQuery` looking like `select g from Group g left join fetch g.members` on top of your `Group` class and use this query with the Hibernate session. Then you would use a query like `select g from Group g left join fetch g.members where g.id = :id` and get the result then.